# how to setting the slurm.conf for worktation

Tags: slurm

My workstation uses 2 Xeon CPU that has 24cores 48threads. I configured the slurm.conf on my workstation as follows:

*

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator easy.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ControlMachine=XXX-Workstation
#ControlAddr=
#
#MailProg=/bin/mail
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
#SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
#SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm-llnl
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
#
#
# TIMERS
#KillWait=30
#MinJobAge=300
#SlurmctldTimeout=120
#SlurmdTimeout=300
#
#
# SCHEDULING
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
#SelectType=select/linear
#SelectTypeParameters=
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core_Memory
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
ClusterName=cluster
#JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
#SlurmctldDebug=3
#SlurmctldLogFile=
#SlurmdDebug=3
#SlurmdLogFile=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=XXX-Workstation CPUs=48 RealMemory=32044 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=XXX-Workstation Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

- 

1. To run my computational code (OpenMP), I use the batch file below. However, when I submit the job script with the number of --cpus-per-task rather than 20 (for example: 12, 30, or 40), the code running time is very slow???

- 

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=testOMP # Job name
#SBATCH --nodes=1 # Run all processes on a single node
#SBATCH --ntasks=1 # Run a single task
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20 # Number of CPU cores per task
#SBATCH --hint=nomultithread # Get physical cores not logical
#SBATCH --exclusive # Job memory request (All available memory)
#SBATCH --time=20:00:00 # Time limit hrs:min:sec
#SBATCH --output=omp%j.out # Name of output file
#SBATCH --error=omp%j.out # Name of error file
# cleans out modules loaded by default
module purge
# load modules
module load intel
# echo of launcher commands
set -x
# number of OMP threads
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
# Binding
export OMP_PLACES=cores
./2D-TFlow2Wall-UPWIND-HKO
```

- 

2. Besides, the workstation has a total 32Gb, but I can not specify the amount of memory to use. The program uses only 2Gb automatically.

Could you please give me a recommendation for these problems!
Thank you very much!